# Get string between two different characters SQL vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

My data is URL

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com/abc/sometihng-herer?&jhdsfj@38736
```

Output I am looking is from 3rd occurance of '/' till before '?'

sample output:

```
 /abc/sometihng-herer
```

Database is vertica and datatype is long char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex substring approach here:

```sql
SELECT url, REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, 'https?://[^/]+(/[^?]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) AS path
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufNiTn/1) showing that the logic is working.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works....but came to know that sometimes it'll be ? and sometime it can be '#' too, can you please help here

Comment: @SQLLER In that case, use this regex pattern: `https?://[^/]+(/[^?#]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `SPLIT_PART`, once with the slash, once with the question mark:

```
WITH
indata(url) AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/abc/sometihng-herer?&jhdsfj@38736'
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT_PART(url,'/',5) AS sp5 -- it is the fifth slash-delimited token of the url
, SPLIT_PART(sp5,'?',1) AS whatwewant
FROM indata;
-- out               sp5              |   whatwewant    
-- out -------------------------------+-----------------
-- out  sometihng-herer?&jhdsfj@38736 | sometihng-herer
```